# Springboot-JPA-Thymeleaf -Bootstrap. How do I refresh a filtered table contents after updating a field using a Modal form

Tags: bootstrap-4, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have a table of projects populated with the below Controller code

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listProjects(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("projects", this.projectService.getProjects());
    return "my-projects";
}
```

I select a row to display a list of Assignments associated with a project

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/getAssignmentsByProjectId", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public String getAssignmentsById(Model model, Long id) {
    model.addAttribute("header", "Assignments for Project - " + this.projectService.getProjectNameById(id));
    model.addAttribute("assignments", this.assignmentService.getAssignmentsByProjectId(id));
    return "project-assignments";
}
```

I then edit a row to change a value using a Modal Form and some JS

```
@RequestMapping("/getAssignmentById")
@ResponseBody
public Assignment getAssignmentById(Long id) {
    Assignment assignment = this.assignmentService.getAssignmentById(id);
    return assignment;
}
```

Then I write the update back to the database from the modal form

```
@RequestMapping("/updateAssignment")
public String getAssignmentById(Long id, Double rate){
    this.assignmentService.updateAssignmentById(id,rate);
    return "project-assignments";
}
```

The modal closes and my list of assignments now has no rows.

How do I refresh the list of assignments, still filtered by the same ProjectId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you do an AJAX request to get the information to show in the modal dialog and you use a regular form POST to actually update the information.

I guess that this snippet:

```
@RequestMapping("/updateAssignment")
public String getAssignmentById(Long id, Double rate){
    this.assignmentService.updateAssignmentById(id,rate);
    return "project-assignments";
}
```

should be done like this:

```
@PostMapping("/updateAssignment")
public String updateAssignmentById(Long id, Double rate){
    this.assignmentService.updateAssignmentById(id,rate);
    return "redirect:/getAssignmentsByProjectId?id=" + id;
}
```

This would redirect the user after the update to the correct URL to show the assignments for a given project id.

Comment: That headed me in the right direction thankyou Wim. I just had to pass in the project Id and change the redirect to "redirect:/projects/getAssignmentsByProjectId/?id=" + projectId; and its working great!